# Getting the ID's of div tags

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML snippet

```
<div id="column_1">
    <div id="portlet_1">
        <div id="portlet-header_1"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_1"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_1"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_1"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portlet_2">
        <div id="portlet-header_2"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_2"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_2"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_2"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="column_2">
    <div id="portlet_3">
        <div id="portlet-header_3"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_3"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_3"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_3"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portlet_4">
        <div id="portlet-header_4"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_4"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_4"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_4"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I:

1. get the column id depending on which close button is clicked?  So if close_button is clicked which is in portlet-header_3, it should return column_2
2. get the portlet id depending on which close button is clicked?  So if close_button is clicked which is in portlet-header_1, it should return portlet_1

I have the following, but this returns the closest div, portlet-header_*, which is not what I am after:

```
$(".close_button").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var that = this;
    alert( $(that).closest("div").attr("id") )
});
```

Comment: When you create the button can you pass in which div to return, and have it be part of the event handler?

Comment: @James that sounds like an awful lot of work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (using jQuery [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)):

```
$(".close_button").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var that = this;
    alert( $(that).parents("[id^=column_]").attr("id") )
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3EJBC/

Comment: parents?  What is this madness? /me runs off to look at api.jquery.com

Comment: IMO parents was an awful name, it should have been `ancestors`

Comment: @jcolebrand -- as opposed to `.closest` which goes up **and** down. `.parents` only goes up the tree

Comment: @Neal ~ I didn't know closest went up and down. Thanks for that brief lesson :D

Comment: @Neal, you are.. `.closest` deals with ancestors-or-self (*but limits it result set to the first it encounters*)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use classes as well, and use `.closest(selector)` or you would need to do `parent().parent().pa...` up the tree to the one you wanted. `.closest(selector)` is much easier and allows you to add new elements later inbetween and inline.

That's two options.

Here's what it would look like in practice:

```
<div id="column_1" class="columns">
    <div id="portlet_1" class="portlets">
        <div id="portlet-header_1"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_1"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_1"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_1"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portlet_2" class="portlets">
        <div id="portlet-header_2"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_2"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_2"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_2"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="column_2" class="columns">
    <div id="portlet_3" class="portlets">
        <div id="portlet-header_3"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_3"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_3"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_3"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
    <div id="portlet_4" class="portlets">
        <div id="portlet-header_4"> <input type="button" class="close_button"> </div>
        <div id="portlet-sub-header_4"> sub header goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-content_4"> content goes here </div>
        <div id="portlet-footer_4"> footer goes here </div>
    </div>
</div>

function (){
  var column_id = $(this).closest('.columns').attr('id')
  var portlet_id = $(this).closest('.portlets').attr('id')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the closest parent div with id starting with 'column` like so:

```
$(that).closest("div[id^='column']").attr("id");
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/utuSz/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".close_button").live('click', function(event) {     
    event.preventDefault();       
    var that = this;     
    alert( $(that).closest("div[id^='column_']").attr("id") ) ; // For column
    alert( $(that).closest("div[id^='portlet-header_']").attr("id") ) ; // For portlet
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var columnId = $(this).closest("div[id^='column'").attr("id");
var portletId = $(this).closest("div[id^='portlet'").attr("id");
```